# Coverage Turn Table to Turn Feature Class in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, feature-class, turns

I have data about streets in coverage format (arc, node and turntable). I would like to transform that data to ArcGIS Pro and use Network Analyst for calculating navigation.

Steps, that I used:

1. I created new gdb and added to it arc and node (I used import feature class)
2. I used function: Turn table to Turn Feature class and got Turn Feature Class
3. I created network dataset
4. As Source Feature Classes I used: arc, node and turn
5. When I want to calculate route, my network dataset does not recognize forbidden turns

How can I get the network to recognize forbidden turns?

Comment: Has this issue happened before when using the route analysis for ArcMap? If possible, could you run the same analysis in Pro? This has happened to me before in Pro, but I was calculating the wrong field, so the network analysis was ignoring my restrictions.

Comment: I made a network dataset in ArcMap because I don't know how to change some properties of the network dataset in ArcGIS Pro. Based on it, I tried to calculate Route in ArcMap and also in ArcGIS Pro but network analysis ignored my restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Under the Route Tab, you can select the corner Travel Settings and set the travel mode to address your U-Turns if those are forbidden. Here is the U-turn policies reference: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/networks/u-turn-policies.htm

You will need to add the Coded Value example: 1: Right side of Vehicle etc, in your data in the attribute table, if you want your route to respect certain curb approaches.